# Missing required client configuration options: region

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to check bucket existence on Amazon S3 using below code:

```
$credentials = new Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials($creds['access_key_id'], $creds['secret_access_key']);
$client = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array( 'credentials' => $credentials ) );
if( ! $client->doesBucketExist($creds['bucket']) ) {
    throw new Exception("Bucket (" . $creds['bucket'] . ") does not exist.");
}
```

It is working on localhost (wamp) but when I tried this on server it is not working. I am getting following error:

> Missing required client configuration options: region: (string) A "region" configuration value is required for the "s3" service (e.g., "us-west-2"). A list of available public regions and endpoints can be found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html. version: (string) A "version" configuration value is required. Specifying a version constraint ensures that your code will not be affected by a breaking change made to the service. For example, when using Amazon S3, you can lock your API version to "2006-03-01". Your build of the SDK has the following version(s) of "s3": * "2006-03-01" You may provide "latest" to the "version" configuration value to utilize the most recent available API version that your client's API provider can find. Note: Using 'latest' in a production application is not recommended. A list of available API versions can be found on each client's API documentation page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/index.html. If you are unable to load a specific API version, then you may need to update your copy of the SDK.

I don't know why it is not working on server but same code is working on localhost.

Comment: you probably have a default region setup in your aws profile (.aws folder in your home directory) on localhost but not on the server?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and I needed to clear my config cache to fix it.

```
$ artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

Set region explicitly when creating s3 client instead of relying on defaults.

```
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$result = $stsClient->getSessionToken();

$credentials = new Credentials(
    $result['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    $result['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    $result['Credentials']['SessionToken']
);

$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'version'     => '2006-03-01',
    'region'      => 'us-west-2',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
```

Comment: why do I need to provide `Aws\Credentials\Credentials` instead of `Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials`

Comment: Depends on aws-sdk-php version you use. 2.8 vs 3.0 Common went away. See [1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/master/src/Credentials) vs [2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/2.8/src/Aws/Common/Credentials)

Answer (score 3):

Check `.env` file variables are matching with `filesystems.php`

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('S3_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('S3_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('S3_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'),
        ],
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

1) Ensure you have `S3_KEY, S3_SECRET, S3_REGION, S3_BUCKET` etc configured in your `.env` file

2) Your environment file might have changed after the autoload/caches were generated. Run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```